# icmp_hdr is wrong on CentOS 6 kernels

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

I have a simple netfilter module to test icmp_hdr function:

```
unsigned int hook_func(
    unsigned int hooknum,
    struct sk_buff *skb,
    const struct net_device *in,
    const struct net_device *out,
    int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{    
    const struct iphdr *ip_header = ip_hdr(skb);
    if (ip_header && ip_header->protocol == IPPROTO_ICMP)
    {
        const struct icmphdr *icmp_header = icmp_hdr(skb);    
        printk(KERN_INFO "ICMP type %d", icmp_header->type);
    }

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

static int __init startup(void)
{
    hook_ops.hook     = hook_func;
    hook_ops.hooknum  = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
    hook_ops.pf       = PF_INET;
    hook_ops.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    nf_register_hook(&hook_ops);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I start to PING the HOST.

On CentOS 6 (2.6.32-754.12.1.el6.x86_64), he printed ICMP type is always `69 (INVALID)`.

On CentOS 7 (3.10) the result is `ICMP_ECHO (8)`, which is correct.

Any ideas? Was there a bug in 2.6.32 kernel?

Comment: Which iptables chain do you use?

Comment: @red0ct It was PRE_ROUTING

Comment: @red0ct Updated answer with nf register part

Comment: Tried another chain LOCAL_IN, same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some difference between mentioned Linux kernels.
In 3.10 kernel we can see the transport header setting in [`ip_rcv()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L437) such way:

```
skb->transport_header = skb->network_header + iph->ihl*4;
```

So the transport header is already set before `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` hooks.

In 2.6 kernel I see nothing similar up to [`ip_local_deliver_finish()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32.71/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L199):

```
__skb_pull(skb, ip_hdrlen(skb));

/* Points to the IP datagram, just past the header. */
skb_reset_transport_header(skb);
```

It's just right after `NF_INET_LOCAL_IN` hooks. So it seems you can't access ICMP-header such a way in mentioned hooks on 2.6.32 kernel. But you can easy make some workaround :)